# When setting variable to double AND adding a double to an integer, why does an integer value come out?

Tags: c++, double

I'm trying to make a code that returns factorials of integers as doubles. However, every time I use the code, it does not return doubles. It always returns integers.

I would like for the code to return the factorial trailed by zeroes.

Ex. 5! = 120.0000, not just 120.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double fac_total=1.0;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    for (int x=1; x <= number; x++)
        fac_total = x*(fac_total+0.0);
    return fac_total;
}
```

Comment: 'return fac_total;' float WHAT...............?

Answer (score 6):

Because `int main()` returns integers...

Comment: Would there be any other way to make a main function that doesn't only return integers?

Comment: @Ambrosios No, in C++, `main` always returns `int`. This is basic, go read your book.

Comment: And not only does it return integers only, it should only return _exit codes_, not results of calculations. That's a job for the _output_ of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Like @djechlin said, the return type for the main function is an int, therefore it will only return integers. 
Why do you want to return a double though? Are you using a bash script on the result of the calculation? 
I noticed you are using cin, so why don't you just use

```
    cout << fac_total << endl;
```

before the return statement. (then return 0;)

Comment: I wanted to test out a function that I was making by creating a separate program for it, but it seems that this function would only properly work if I included it as part of a program rather than on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return anything but an `int` from `main` if you want to keep your program conform to the standard.

Besides, return value of `0` is meant to indicate success and a non-zero value is meant to indicate failure. You probably should print the number to `stdout` and return `0` from `main`.

```
int main()
{
    double fac_total=1.0;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    for (int x=1; x <= number; x++)
        fac_total = x*(fac_total+0.0);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << fac_total << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can capture the output of the program using the facilities provided by the console/shell.

Make sure to add

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
```

to be able to use `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed`.